# Prolog write list function exit condition

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I'm new to Prolog and am trying to define a simple function that writes a list. So far I have;

```
printList([Head|Tail]) :-
  write(Head), nl,
  printList(Tail).
```

When I call this function like `printList([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])` it writes:

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
[5,6]
false
```

The output above is correct except for the false that shows at the bottom of the list. I assume is shows false because There isn't some kind of exit condition on the `printList` function to control for when the list is empty. How would I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly!!! you need a rule for empty list. Just write:

```
printList([]).
printList([Head|Tail]) :-
  write(Head), nl,
  printList(Tail).
```

Example:

```
?- printList([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]).
[1,2]
[3,4]
[5,6]
true.
```

Comment: Ahh, it's so simple. Thanks! :)